# WM_SETICON not working when program launched via shortcut

Tags: c++, windows, icons, shortcut, sendmessage

I am using WM_SETICON to change the icon of an application.  This works when the program is run in VisualStudio debugger, or via commandline, but uses the wrong taskbar icon when launched through a desktop shortcut on Windows 7.  Right clicking to pin the program to the taskbar and then unpinning it causes the icon to display correctly.

```
HICON icon = (HICON) LoadImage(NULL, iconStr, IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32,   LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_SHARED);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)icon);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)icon);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL2, (LPARAM)icon);
```

It seems as though something about launching through a shortcut is causing the program to use a stale cached icon and ignore WM_SETICON.  Also the small icon next to the program titlebar is updating properly, it is only the icon on the taskbar that has issues.

I really do need to set the icon programatically because it will change based on commandline.  Does anyone know of a way to make this work?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I did find a workaround.  Since the exe referenced by the shortcuts can't change it's icon, it can launch an exe with a different filename that will then be able to change taskbar icons with WM_SETICON.

shortcuts (1-n) each have their own icon and point to IgnoresWMSetIcon.exe.
On startup IgnoresWMSetIcon.exe launches CanChangeIcon.exe then closes.  CanChangeIcon.exe is then able to function normally.

Still interested in an explanation of why this is the case, if someone knows.